# Should ecapsulated objects be public or private?

Tags: oop, class-design, encapsulation

I'm a little unclear as to how far to take the idea in making all members within a class private and make public methods to handle mutations.  Primitive types are not the issue, it's encapsulated object that I am unclear about.  The benefit of making object members private is the ability to hide methods that do not apply to the context of class being built.  The downside is that you have to provide public methods to pass parameters to the underlying object (more methods, more work).  On the otherside, if you want to have all methods and properties exposed for the underlying object, couldn't you just make the object public?  **What are the dangers in having objects exposed this way?**

For example, I would find it useful to have everything from a vector, or  Array List, exposed.  The only downside I can think of is that public members could potentially assigned a type that its not via implicit casting (or something to that affect).  Would a volitile designation reduce the potential for problems?

Just a side note:  I understand that true enapsulation implies that members are private.

Comment: See the Law of Demeter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter, in an OOP language you should seek to minimize dependencies.
It depends whether the "class" truly has functionality, or is actually a data structure.  If it's just a data structure the getters 'n' setters seem overkill, especially if all the fields can be immutable (final).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the dangers in having objects exposed this way?

Changing the type of those objects would require changing the interface to the class. With private objects + public getters/setters, you'd only have to modify the code in the getters and setters, assuming you want to keep the things being returned the same.

Note that this is why properties are useful in languages such as Python, which technically doesn't have private class members, only obscured ones at most.

Comment: But don't you think this is the consequence of declaring `private objects + public getters/setters` ? what if he declares everything public ? Though not advisable due to many other reasons i don't think the answer justifies the question

Comment: "what if he declares everything public?" Then there's no encapsulation and changing a member of a class that's directly exposed would require changing anything that accesses that directly-exposed member and expects it to behave in a certain way. You're thinking about it a bit backwards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with making instance variables public is that you can never change your mind later, and make them private, without breaking existing code that relies on directly public access to those instance vars. Some examples:

- You decide to later make your class thread-safe by synchronizing all access to instance vars, or maybe by using a ThreadLocal to create a new copy of the value for each thread. Can't do it if any thread can directly access the variables.
- Using your example of a vector or array list - at some point, you realize that there is a security flaw in your code because those classes are mutable, so somebody else can replace the contents of the list. If this were only available via an accessor method, you could easily solve the problem by making an immutable copy of the list upon request, but you can't do that with a public variable.
- You realize later that one of your instance vars is redundant and can be derived based on other variables. Once again, easy if you're using accessors, impossible with public variables.

I think that it boils down to a practical point - if you know that you're the only one who will be using this code, and it pains you to write accessors (every IDE will do it for you automatically), and you don't mind changing your own code later if you decide to break the API, then go for it. But if other people will be using your class, or if you would like to make it easier to refactor later for your own use, stick with accessors.

Answer (score 0):

Object oriented design is just a guideline. Think about it from the perspective of the person who will be using your class. Balance OOD with making it intuitive and easy to use.

Comment: Well put. Then you would want your naming convention to align to the to design of the class. So if you had a public vector of integers meant to hold prime numbers, I suppose it would be poor form to give a name like "PrimeVector"

Comment: Obviously you'd want to call it "VectorPrime".

Comment: So much is based upon the details of your task at hand. If, for example, we're talking Java, where Vector is a well known class *and* you are designing the class to be used by Java programs, then my preference would be to have it named something like "PrimeNumbers" and of the type Vector. If you are in a different language where you rolled your own class named Vector, you would need to also expose that class in your interface. If you are doing an interface that's not strongly typed, I'd call it "PrimeNumbersVector". Also, if you are writing a COM interface there are other considerations.

Comment: @JAB If only there were an Optimus class. ;-)

Comment: Brighwell - Uptick for COM reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could run into issues depending on the language you are using and how it treats return statements or assignment operators. In some cases it may give you a reference, or values in other cases.

For example, say you have a PrimeCalculator class that figures out prime numbers, then you have another class that does something with those prime numbers.

```
public PrimeCalculator calculatorObject = new PrimeCalculator();

Vector<int> primeNumbers = calculatorObject.PrimeNumbersVector;
/* do something complicated here */
primeNumbers.clear(); // free up some memory
```

When you use this stuff later, possibly in another class, you don't want the overhead of calculating the numbers again so you use the same calculatorObject.

```
Vector<int> primes = calculatorObject.PrimeNumbersVector;
int tenthPrime = primes.elementAt(9);
```

It may not exactly be clear at this point whether primes and primeNumbers reference the same Vector. If they do, trying to get the tenth prime from primes would throw an error.

You can do it this way if you're careful and understand what exactly is happening in your situation, but you have a smaller margin of error using functions to return a value rather than assigning the variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can check the post :

[first this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555866/unencapsulated-means-unchangeable/6555928#6555928)

[then this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561443/do-both-these-classes-support-encapsulation-and)

This should solve your confusion . **It solved mine ! Thanks to [Nicol Bolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas).**

Also read the comments below the accepted answer *(also notice the link given in the second last comment by me ( in the first post) )*

Also visit [the wikipedia post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)