# Unencapsulated means Unchangeable?

Tags: c++, oop, encapsulation, public

I came across this line in *Effective C++*:

> Public means unencapsulated, and practically speaking, unencapsulated means unchangeable, especially
>   for classes that are widely used.Yet widely used classes are most in need of encapsulation, because
>   they are the ones that can most benefit from the ability to replace one implementation with a better
>   one

What does the author mean by "Public means unencapsulated, and practically speaking, unencapsulated means unchangeable"?

And how is unencapsulated unchangeable?

Comment: @ Martinho Fernandes Any specific reason to remove java tag ?

Comment: Gupta: Because the book is specifically talking about C++.

Comment: @ DeadMG But it is a general oop question. I could remove the first line in my question .

Comment: @Suhail: yes, it is a general OOP question. That's why it _shouldn't_ have the Java tag. Or the C++ tag. Because it's not about any particular language; it's about encapsulation in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general idea is simple. If you make something public, then someone can and probably will use it. Therefore, if you *change* something that is public, all of the code that uses it immediately breaks. Breaking people's code is bad; it tends to lead to them not wanting to use your code anymore, since now you've forced them to rewrite all of their stuff just because you wanted to use a different type or something.

The public interface is a contract between the implementation of the class and the user of it. Changing that contract, particularly without advanced notice, is considered very rude.

If all of your code is internal, that's fine. But if it's not, if you're making a library for others to use (whether locally or just selling a library), then people are less likely to be happy about interface changes.

It isn't a matter of rules of C++; it's simply a matter of rules of interface design. Since public things are part of the interface, you must be careful about what you make public.

Comment: ...and what could be the need to change ?

Comment: @Suhail: The idea is to _never_ need to change. That's why you must carefully select what you make public. If you do it right, you will have the freedom to change the implementation details without changing the interface.

Comment: @ Nicol Bolas How will your statement **"The idea is to never need to change."** fail if i make all my members public ?

Comment: @Suhail: Because we're assuming that you're working in software development, where you need to _change_ implementations. Some of those members don't need to be public because they're implementation dependent. If you are able to write something once and never have to touch it, that's great. But do you want to take the chance that you will never have to touch the implementation, or do you want to actually use encapsulation and data hiding to make the inevitable implementation changes possible without affecting the interface?

Comment: @Suhail: An example. Suppose you have a class that represents the position and orientation of an object, and suppose these objects can be rigidly attached to and detached to one another. When you move one object you want the whole chain of connected objects to move as one. Keeping things consistent is the responsibility of some method, call it update. If the data can only be set by some setter, that setter can ensure that update() is called: State is guaranteed to be consistent. If the data are exposed, some user is inevitably going to tweak the state but not call update().

Comment: @David: that is different from changing the implementation, it's about maintaining invariants (which is also important, but not the question here).

Comment: @ Nicol Bolas I think i am able to feel better now , but one question **Can't i refactor my code with as much ease if i had declared data members public ?**

Comment: @Suhail: And how exactly would you do that? If your refactoring includes removing public data members, then you're changing the interface. And that means you're breaking other people's code. Which is precisely what refactoring is _not_ supposed to do.

Comment: @ Nicol Bolas [Can you give the advantage here in this small code](http://suhail03.my3gb.com/Encapsulation.html)

Comment: @Suhail: that's a new question. And it's too complex to answer in a simple comment. But consider what happens if you want `NormalFieldClass` to hold a first name and a last name, separately. In the encapsulated version, the user can set both names with the old "setName" function, but they can also use the new "setFirstName" and "setLastName" functions. The unencapsulated version cannot be upgraded without breaking existing code, since users just bang on the data directly.

Comment: @ Nicol Bolas I modified the normal class and [posted it as....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561443/do-both-these-classes-support-encapsulation-and)

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulation is the idea that you can access the data member of a class only through interface methods. The effect of using a method is "hiding" the actual implementation of the data member, so that you can change it without the need to change the code that uses that class through the interface methods (provided you don't change the way they are defined).

On the other hand, if you don't use interface methods to hide the data member implementation, all your code that uses it will need to be modified in front of any change in the data member.

Say that you have a class with a vector of strings containing a list of names. If you make public that vector, then all other classes can decide to directly use it, and access the strings it contains by their index in the vector (the index acts as a key to identify the string, say).

Later, you could decide you need a map to manage all those strings (your requirement have changed). You change the data member definition to a map and your code will not compile anymore. This is the meaning of "practically unchangeable".

The "right" way to manage this through encapsulation is making the data member private and define an interface method like:

```
std::string getStringWithKey(int index);
```

this method will access the vector in the first implementation, and the map in the second case. All this in a transparent way: the code that uses the method (instead of accessing directly the data member) will not need to be modified, so you can change the data member implementation as you like at almost no cost.

This is an oversimplification, because design of interfaces is not a simple matter and interfaces also do change, but I hope it helps clarifying things.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the best answer would be given by the author. My guess is that he means that if you declare a public member and use it on many other places in your code, then it would be hard work to change all those places if you later decide to change that member.

Answer (score 0):

He is referring to data members, and he is saying that publicly exposing data members as part of the public interface means that you can never change their *nature,* i.e. name and type.

Comment: Can i never change the name and type of data members declared public  ? !

Comment: No no, not as in "constant", but rather as in "you cannot change your design after you've published your interface", because your users will already have started using the public members.

Comment: @ Kerrek SB why i cannot change the design after i've published my interface with public members ?

Comment: @Suhail because client code will be using, and relying on, what you have published. If you start changing your public interface the clients will have to adapt their code.

Comment: @ juanchopanza and what benefit i will score when i have _appropriately_ selected public members ?